# Sql Query distinct select

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

My table:

```
0010121301  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    9.000
0010121302  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    30.000
0010121303  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    10.000
0010121304  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    10.000
0010121305  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    20.000
0010121306  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    10.000
0010121395  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1000    20170911    10.000
0010121399  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1000    20170911    10.000
0010121502  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1033    20170911    5.000
0010121515  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1023    20170911    10.000
```

How can I use a query to get the following result from the table in the remainder of the table?

I tried many methods but without success.

```
0010121302  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1020    20170911    30.000
0010121395  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1000    20170911    10.000
0010121502  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1033    20170911    5.000
0010121515  000000000001000057  TULUMBA KG  KG  1023    20170911    10.000
```

Here the WERKS field will be singular plus all fields in the record that are the largest MENGE field for each werks field

Comment: Distinct how? Explain.

Comment: What is the logic you are looking for? What have you tried? You will get better answers if you don't leave us to guess. Also show column name

Comment: why exactly these four lines? How do they differ from the others?

Comment: Column Names:BANFN MATNR TXZ01 MEINS WERKS LFDAT MENGE

Comment: Here the WERKS field will be singular. plus all fields in the record that are the largest MENGE field for each werks field

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Add column names inside your tables in your questions please. It makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that;

```
select * from YourTable Y1 inner join 
(select WERKS, MAX(MENGE) as MaxMENGE from 
YourTable group by WERKS) Y2 ON Y1.WERKS = Y2.WERKS and Y1.MENGE = Y2.MaxMENGE
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be done like this. However im not sure i got all your columns correct. Please add columnnames to your data in your question.

```
With maxvalues as ( select max(MENGE) as MaxPrice,MATNR,TXZ01,MEINS,WERKS,LFDAT FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY MATNR,TXZ01,MEINS,WERKS,LFDAT
)

Select a.BAFNR,b.* from MYTABLE A
inner join MAXVALUES B on a.WERKS = b.WERKS and A.MENGE = b.MENGE
```

Answer (score 0):

As no `rdbms` is mentioned, so assuming the window `OLAP` functions are supported, you can use `row_number()` as below.

```
select t2.banfn, t2.matnr, t2.txz01, t2.meins, t2.col1, t2.werks, t2.lfdat, t2.menge 
from (
     select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by werks order by menge desc) as rn
     from table1 t1
     ) t2
where rn = 1
order by t2.banfn;
```

**Result:**

```
+----------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+----------+-------+
|  banfn   |  matnr  |  txz01  | meins | col1 | werks |  lfdat   | menge |
+----------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+----------+-------+
| 10121302 | 1000057 | TULUMBA | KG    | KG   |  1020 | 20170911 |    30 |
| 10121395 | 1000057 | TULUMBA | KG    | KG   |  1000 | 20170911 |    10 |
| 10121502 | 1000057 | TULUMBA | KG    | KG   |  1033 | 20170911 |     5 |
| 10121515 | 1000057 | TULUMBA | KG    | KG   |  1023 | 20170911 |    10 |
+----------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+----------+-------+
```

**[row_number() DEMO](http://rextester.com/XDLAS51419)**

---

If `row_number` is not supported, you can use correlated query and aggregation

```
select min(t1.banfn) as banfn, t1.matnr, t1.txz01, t1.col1, t1.werks, t1.lfdat, t1.menge
from table1 t1
where t1.menge = 
    (select max(t2.menge)
    from table1 t2
    where t1.werks = t2.werks
     ) 
group by t1.matnr, t1.txz01, t1.col1, t1.werks, t1.lfdat, t1.menge  
order by banfn
```

**[Correlated-Query DEMO](http://rextester.com/EBRMY85400)**

Answer (score -1):

As you have said that you wants only distinct results without any other condition, You should try something like ...

```
{select * from TABLE_NAME  group by  DISTINCT_COLUMN_NAME}
```

`Change vars in CAPS to actual name.`

You may use `ORDER BY` clause to order